# Is run Method is only way to achieve Multi Threading

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to run simultaneously two different methods in two different classes
Is run method is the only way? 
If it is Why??

Comment: https://pastebin.com/4G1zHajA   //In that I can able to run simultaneously Run method() .but am unable to run display()method why?

Comment: Please post code as formatted code blocks in the question (use the [edit] link).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code snippet does not show how you actually start these threads, I am assuming something like `new Thread2().start()`. What this does is create a new thread and the new thread proceeds (in the background) to execute its `run` method (and then terminates when that method returns).

Every thread runs code that is contained with a `run()` method. That is just how threads work. There has to be some convention to let the JVM know where the code for the thread is.

From within that method, you can call any other method on any other object that you have access to.